# Google Feed API - Failed to load images from Feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss, google-feed-api

i am trying to load more than one feed in a website with Google Feed Api. 
I have problem to load images to my feeds and cant find a solution. Can enybody help me? Below is a codepen.

the feed has this markup:

```
<img>http://img.ephoto.sk/images/content/articles/c285367e4e39cfa8056f2c95ec715f76c1e758af.jpg</img>
```

JS Code:

```
function parseFeed(url, container) {
$.ajax({
    url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=5&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url), // "num=5" will show 5 articles
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        // log object data in console
        console.log(data.responseData.feed);
        // for each entry... *
        $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (key, value) {
            var title = '<li><a class="title" href="' + value.link + '" target="_blank">' + value.title + '</a></li>';
                    var image = '<img class="thumbnail" src="' + value.img + '">';
            var entry = '<div class="entry"><ul>' + image + title +  '</ul></div>';
            // * append entire entry in container
            $(container).append(entry);
        });
    },
    // if there's an error... *
    error: function (errorThrown) {
        // * log error message in console
        console.log(errorThrown);
        // * show error message
        alert('Niekde vo feede sa vyskytla chyba.');
    }
});
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    parseFeed('http://feeds.feedburner.com/FotoportlEphotosk-FotoFotografieFotoaparty', '#ephoto');
});
```

Codepen:
http://codepen.io/MichalSK/pen/rVEwPy

Is there also any solution to make this code to work with this markup?

```
<image>
<url>http://...</url>
<title>Lorem ipsum</title>
<pubDate>Wed, 19 Aug 2015 13:00:00 +0200</pubDate>
<link>http://...</link>
</image>
```

I hope this will help also other folks that are looking to work with Google Feed Api.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have img parameter in `data.responseData.feed.entries` parameters ? your `value.link` is fetching values of link parameter from parameters of `data.responseData.feed.entries` but you don't have "img" parameter to fetch its value for

`var image = '<img class="thumbnail" src="' + value.img + '">';`

So you need store link of your image in `data` object you are loading, before you fetch undefined parameter.

Code below shows images, because there is defined link for those images. in `data.responseData.feed.entries.value` there is no `img` parameter to get the link through its value

```js
function parseFeed(url, container) {
$.ajax({
    url: document.location.protocol 
         + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=5&callback=?&q=' 
         + encodeURIComponent(url), // "num=5" will show 5 articles
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        // log object data in console
        console.log(data.responseData.feed);
        // for each entry... *
        $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (key, value) {
            //valid link to image source                
            var img = "http://rocketdock.com/images/screenshots/Debian-Logo.png"
            var title = '<li><a class="title" href="' + value.link 
            + '" target="_blank">' + value.title + '</a></li>';
            var image = '<img class="thumbnail" src="' + img + '">';
            var entry = '<div class="entry"><ul>' + image + title +  '</ul></div>';
            // * append entire entry in container
            $(container).append(entry);
        });
    },
    // if there's an error... *
    error: function (errorThrown) {
        // * log error message in console
        console.log(errorThrown);
        // * show error message
        alert('Niekde vo feede sa vyskytla chyba.');
    }
});
}
$(document).ready(function () {
   parseFeed('http://feeds.feedburner.com/FotoportlEphotosk-FotoFotografieFotoaparty',
 '#ephoto');
});
```

```css
html,body {
background-color:#222;
color:#fff;
font-family:"Noto Sans", sans-serif;
font-size:1em;
font-weight:400;
line-height:1.45;
}

a{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
img{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <div id="ephoto"></div>
</div>
```

Check your data from console you don't find `img` parameter.

Comment: Thx, but how do i store a link of every image in feed?

Comment: if you want only one image to be loaded then add one, if you want different images in every list then make an object or an array for the list of images. Then you can call them via parameters of object

Comment: Yes, but i dont know how to load the image, this var img = "http://rocketdock.com/images/screenshots/Debian-Logo.png" is not very helpfull.

Comment: How are you loading the image? from your storage or via web-link?   [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp) is guide on loading images

Comment: I need to pull the images from RSS feed, thats the problem i am encountering.